# Using javascript to call a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a javascript (.js) file, and I'm trying to use it to call a php script. All the php script does is log something to a database. I want the javascript to run a certain function, and when it does, it will prompt the php script to run and log something to the database.

A lot of online sources have told me to use jQuery for this, though I'm a little confused. Isn't jQuery specifically attached to HTML DOMs? I just want the php file to log whenever a specific javascript.

I did trying using ajax for this, and here's my code:
    var urlRequest = $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "php/logging.php",
        dataType: "script"
    });
However, I'm getting a very strange
    Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at HTMLLIElement.readyClicked (lobby.js:192)

Comment: You don't *need* to use jQuery.  AJAX functions are one of the things jQuery does, but any AJAX will do.

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` Add this to your HTML.